# Why is my function failing to conditionally render images?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

friends. Please see the map function I wrote below. My goal is to render an image for each sport in the this.state.sports array. I've written some functionality to get record a variable that would capture the appropriate image path, where the images are located in my repo (just have one for baseball at the moment for testing, but know I will have to put the others in there eventually), but it's failing to render. I only get the blank image symbol. All of the console logs are coming back exactly how I want them (so it's not a matter of improperly selecting the right data), but it's still failing to work.

```
this.state.sports.map((sport) => {    
     let imgPath = " ";
     if(/\s/g.test(sport.name.toLowerCase())){                                        
        imgPath = '../' + sport.name.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase() + '.png'
      } else {
        imgPath = '../' + sport.name.toLowerCase() + '.png'
      }   

      return(
          <div>
            <img src={imgPath} />
            <button className="sport-button" onClick={() => this.deleteSport(sport.id)}>
              {sport.name}
            </button>                         
          </div>
         )   
       })
```

Here's where my baseball image is being stored - for purpose of confirming the path is correct. This map appears in the List.js component.

[image]

Aaaand what I actually see on the page...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images should typically go into your `public` folder, or even better `public/images`. The `public` is where you would put any file you want to be accessible through a url (images being one of those).

Then you can can just reference them like:

```
imgPath = 'images/' + sport.name.toLowerCase() + '.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also to use require() for this.

```
    imgPath = '../' + sport.name.toLowerCase() + '.png'

    ...

    // Only add this line after setting imgPath
    imgPath = require(imagePath)

    ....

            <img src={imgPath} />
```